# How to replace tray icons for applications in cinnamon

Tags: gnome, icons, cinnamon

I have on my cinnamon panel some tray icons (skype, pidgin, dropbox) that appear next to others coming from cinnamon but that do not fit the general appearance.

[image]

I'd like to replace them with my own icons so that they have similar design to those remaining.

Where should I look for icons for pidgin, skype and dropbox?

Comment: skype icon is tough!

Comment: your terminology is obscure. I have edited to make it clear, but also I should flag it to be closed because it is too general in scope. Or maybe you should edit it or create **separate** questions for the different applications. Dropbox will fit very easily the desktop if you use proper icon set. Skype is very difficult. Somebody has created a separate build only to change the tray icon. I think [one of your links](http://ubuntovod.ru/instructions/skype-icon-unity.html) is to that Russian site. Clementine for example is also difficult to edit. But skype is the toughest.

Comment: I think this question is too large, because **there is no one universal method for changing the system tray icons**. Some changes are easily done through the application itself, **most of them depend on the icon themes**, and changing or editing those may be the best way. But some, like Skype, would not allow changing the tray icon in none of the above ways.

Answer (score 2):

The Skype icon can be replaced by installing a modified version of `sni-qt` which points the location of the tray icons as `/usr/share/pixmaps/skype`.

To do this, enter the following commands in a terminal -

`wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/x91gec5q0uz3hnx/sni-qt_0.2.6-0ubuntu1_i386-modified.deb?dl=0 -O sni-qt_0.2.6-0ubuntu1_i386-modified.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i sni-qt_0.2.6-0ubuntu1_i386-modified.deb`

The above two commands will download and install the modified version of `sni-qt`

Now, we will download and extract the new icon set, which is based on the Faenza Dark theme -

`wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/wimn53noljv0vbi/skype_systemtray_custom_icons.zip?dl=0 -O skype_systemtray_custom_icons.zip`

`unzip skype_systemtray_custom_icons.zip`

The final step is to create a directory /usr/share/pixmaps/skype and copy the icons to it.

`sudo mkdir /usr/share/pixmaps/skype`

`sudo cp skype/* /usr/share/pixmaps/skype`

`sudo chmod +r /usr/share/pixmaps/skype/*`

The result -

Before - [image]

After - [image]

To restore the original configuration -

`sudo apt-get purge sni-qt`

`sudo rm -r /usr/share/pixmaps/skype`

`sudo apt-get install sni-qt`

Credits to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503267/change-skype-tray-icon/549964#549964) and [this website](http://webguruz.ru/ubuntu/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-skype-%D0%B2-ubuntu/).

Comment: `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sni-qt:i386:
 sni-qt:i386 depends on libdbusmenu-qt2 (>= 0.3.2).

dpkg: error processing package sni-qt:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sni-qt:i386`

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f install`. Have you added support for MultiArch?

Comment: how to do add support for MA?

Comment: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Comment: sorry for my previous comment now deleted. my system failing had nothing to do with the above error. after reinstalling the system, after a while it is stuck again on boot without nothing to do with this answer. have to fix this first before being able to test again. my problem is [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90090)

Answer (score 1):

### Where to search for icons

You can look for icons at http://www.iconfinder.com:

- for Pidgin: http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=pidgin
- for Skype: http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=skype
- for Dropbox: http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=dropbox

### Add an application to cinnamon panel

Next I will explain how to add Pidgin to the cinnamon panel bar and how to change its icon.

Let say that your cinnamon panel bar looks something like in the following image in this moment:

[image: cinnamon panel]

To add Pidgin in the panel par, go to **Menu** and search for "Pidgin". When it found, right click on it and select **Add to panel**:

[image: Add app to panel]

So now your panel bar it looks like this:

[image: cinnamon panel]

### Change the icon for an application

Let say that you want to change the default icon for Pidgin to the following:

[image: Pidgin icon]

To change the icon for Pidgin, go to **Menu** search for "Main menu" and open it. When it open, search for "Pidgin" application, click **Properties** and change the icon by clicking on it:

[image: change icon]
[image: change icon]

So, finally, your panel bar it looks like this:

[image: cinnamon bar]

Moreover, you can move an application anywhere you want on the panel by right clicking on the panel and selecting Panel Edit mode. Now you can drag and drop your application anywhere you want on the panel:

[image: right cinnamon panel]

Comment: You read question? tray - it's [link](http://i46.fastpic.ru/big/2013/0726/c6/6b6e4dda1442eac3252489e25a1d9ac6.png) not section fast exec.

Comment: @plsgogame The word "tray" doesn't exist in Cinnamon terminology. But you can drag and drop your application anywhere you want on the panel: [see here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nsTrx.png) ;)

Comment: ok @Radu Rădeanu, but i need change skype icon, it's not easy. You know how i can it's make.

Comment: @plsgogame Use the same method for Skype or for whatever application. I think I explained quite clearly. Do you want the same explanation for any particular application?

Comment: no, you not understand, i need change skype icon at tray, i need change not shortcut need change system icon, like this [link](http://ubuntovod.ru/instructions/skype-icon-unity.html)

Comment: look last my answer. Thx.@Radu Rădeanu

Comment: @plsgogame Did you even try to change the icon for Skype in Main Menu (alacarte)?

Comment: no i want change skype icon. Not in menu, blue icon on menu does not bother me. I want see on tray(running skype icon) gray icon, not green, not red, not yellow, gray. like previous link.

Comment: @plsgogame If you dont't change the Skype icon in Main Menu (alacarte), how do you think it will change the icon in the panel bar?

Comment: ufff, @Radu Rădeanu, f*cking panel bar!!! Do not you understand what I want... like this [iwant](http://ubuntovod.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/skype-icon-unity.jpg) 
panel bar - it's panel for run applications, tray - it's not panel for run app, it's panel notification about messages, calls, errors and etc...

Comment: you see differences?!

Comment: @plsgogame [That picture](http://ubuntovod.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/skype-icon-unity.jpg) it doesn't have nothing to do with cinnamon.

Comment: Pidgin's Preferences-Interface - System tray icon, Show system tray icon. If set to Always, a Pidgin status icon appears in Cinnamon panel status area (which is a system tray sort of), and that one is not affected by editing the Menu pidgin icon. But **that is what the question asks**. That status icon stays visible as long as the application is open. Clicking it hides/unhides the Buddy list. What you call an application (*"you can move an application anywhere you want on the panel"*) and you edited there is the launching button. That edit also changes the window tab but not the status (tray)

Comment: You say: *"The word "tray" doesn't exist in Cinnamon terminology"* Not true. The term is used to name a panel applet that comes by default in Linux Mint Cinnamon 17. (When I talk about tray in previous comment that is the one involved.) It is called System Tray. Another one [here](http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/154). Also, the term appears when searched [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/search).