# Change skype tray icon

Tags: icons, skype, microsoft

Skype version 4.2 comes with a low res 48x48 statusbar/tray icon. How can I change the icon to a higher resolution icon?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I made a .deb package with a hack that compels sni-qt:i386 to use images located in `/usr/share/pixmaps/skype/` directory for systemtray skype status icons, based on [webguruz.ru](http://webguruz.ru/ubuntu/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-skype-%D0%B2-ubuntu/) page.

### To install

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/x91gec5q0uz3hnx/sni-qt_0.2.6-0ubuntu1_i386-modified.deb?dl=0 -O sni-qt_0.2.6-0ubuntu1_i386-modified.deb

sudo dpkg -i sni-qt_0.2.6-0ubuntu1_i386-modified.deb
```

Then you need to install new icons, for that follow the steps bellow:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/wimn53noljv0vbi/skype_systemtray_custom_icons.zip?dl=0 -O skype_systemtray_custom_icons.zip

unzip skype_systemtray_custom_icons.zip

sudo mkdir /usr/share/pixmaps/skype

sudo cp skype/* /usr/share/pixmaps/skype

sudo chmod +r /usr/share/pixmaps/skype/*
```

The icon set I provide here is based on Faenza-Dark Theme, for change the icons, just replace the images in /usr/share/pixmaps/skype directory.

### To remove

```
sudo dpkg -r sni-qt_0.2.6-0ubuntu1_i386-modified.deb
sudo rm -r /usr/share/pixmaps/skype
```

Comment: I've decided to create script basing on that solution. It's available at https://github.com/pwittchen/fix-skype-icon. I hope someone will find it useful.

Comment: @piotr.wittchen thanks a lot for this, but maybe you might also add the modified deb file as well as mono-dark and mono-light icon sets to that github repository just in case.

Comment: @Sadi I think, you should ask this question to Gabriel Araújo. I haven't prepared any deb files or icons. I just took existing solution and made a shell script out of it.

Comment: @piotr.wittchen Yes, I know, Gabriel should also be seeing these comments, and maybe he'll agree to share them in your  github repository too ;-) BTW there is also another variant (dark ones) of that icon set (I've downloaded it from that website) for light GTK themes.

Comment: after applying this method, is there a way to replace icon with another one?

Comment: @Woeitg Yes, you just need replace icons inside /usr/share/pixmaps/skype directory

Comment: Could you share the patch for that? Now the actual version of sni-qt is `0.2.7`, so you package is not installable anymore :(

Comment: Unfortunately, as of Ubuntu 18.04, the deb package will not install.

Comment: Tried it on Linux Mint 19.1 with Cinnamon but in does not work

Comment: This answer is obsolete.