# What is the must customizable desktop environment?

Tags: themes, icons, desktop-environments, customization, icon-themes

I would like to customize all the icons of my desktop environment, specially change Skype system tray icon which is very ugly! Can you tell me in which [DE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) I can customize all the icons and use those that I prefer?

Comment: The system tray's icon of Skype has nothing to do with the DE. Changeable (in principle) in any DE, *if* you know where it is located. That should be your question.

Comment: Can you tell me where it is located? Well, I also wanted to change other tray icons, skype is the one I really need to change!

Comment: No, I don't have it installed

Comment: Could be interesting if there is a way to locate icons of system tray. for instance power icon, dropbox, telegram, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All DE's are capable of changing icon sets that you can download in their respective "Appearance", or "Look and Feel" menus. You can also manually change each one in file property windows by clicking the icon on the properties page, and choose any icon you want.

To specifically change only Skype's system tray icon, see the answer here : [Change skype tray icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503267/change-skype-tray-icon)

Comment: I am more interested to change skype system tray icon.

Comment: I posted a link to an answer that has instructions on how to do this specifically and involves downloading and installing a custom package.  All instructions are in the link.