# Program for costumizing system tray's icon

Tags: software-recommendation, icons, system-tray, icon-themes

In my [last question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793164/what-is-the-must-customizable-desktop-environment), I figure out that system tray's icon are independent of desktop environment. However seems like there is no straightforward way to find the path to icons. I wonder if there is a program that personalize system tray's icon by asking the user for icons to replace the default one.

For instance I would like to set my own set of icons for Skype, Power, Volume control, Notes, Clipboard, etc.

Comment: Do you mean the launcher?

Comment: no, I mean Skype, power, audio, notes ,etc icons. they are usually beside the clock (depend on DE obviously)

Comment: Have a look at this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/80627/how-can-i-change-the-icon-of-an-application-in-the-unity-launcher