# Skype icons changing, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, icons, skype, qt

There is question about changing skype icons in [ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503267/change-skype-tray-icon). [The answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/549964/445162) works in ubntu 14.04 and uses modified version of sni qt 0.2.6. 
But it is not possible to use this library for ubuntu 16.04, because current sni qt is 0.2.7 and it causes errors.

My question is it possible to check what was changed in modified version of sni qt from [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/549964/445162), and then to change the same in sni qt 0.2.7 sources and install it.

Comment: You probably need the source of the modified package to do it.

Comment: Is it possible to extract sources from .deb file?

Comment: No. And since the file which does the work is a compiled library (`.so` file) there is no other way AFAICT  than getting the source. (OTOH the change to the source is probably not rocket science. It's about changing a path to the locations of the icons. Maybe redoing it might be an interest exercise in Debian/Ubuntu packaging.)